# When i need access methods from other folders in js file

Tags: javascript

I separated javascript functions of the html and created a .js file for it. How do I access methods from other folders through a .js file?

Comment: As long as your JS files are imported in your HTML BEFORE you are accessing the methods you can call them just fine. But I suggest you to look at RequireJS for loading modules when requiring them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="./path/file.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if that's what you want; please provide more details about your question.

Comment: I use VisualStudio 2012 and i have a folder/method: App_Start.Util.Some_Method()

A need access this method, but i'm in Scripts/Some_file.js

Do you understand?

Comment: So where is your `.js` file?

Comment: So `<script src="Scripts/your_file_name_here.js"></script>` should work. Any more question?

Comment: Anyway, i need access the method in other folder.
I'm in Scripts folder.
Ex:
  var language = App_Start.Util.GetSessionInformation("Language");

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: App_Start is not defined.

Comment: You're not making any sense. Obviously, something relevant is missing in your question. Please add the directories hierarchy to it, if you think that's important to the understanding of the problem.